# issue with URLSearchParams in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, urlencode

I am trying to call a POST service with url-encoded data.
i have written my method to convert json to url encoded string.

```
urlEncode(reqData){
if(reqData!=null){
  console.log("reqData encode:"+JSON.stringify(reqData));
  let reqUrlEncodedBody = new URLSearchParams();
  for(let key in reqData){
    console.log("key:"+key+" ,value:"+reqData[key]);
    reqUrlEncodedBody.append((key),encodeURIComponent(reqData[key]));
  }
  console.log("urlencoded string:"+reqUrlEncodedBody.toString());
  return reqUrlEncodedBody.toString();
 }
}
```

now i am passing below object to it:

```
let validateTokenData = 
{
 "grant_type" : "ss:zxz.com:oox:grant_type:some",
 "token":currentAuthToken
};
```

the output string of it is:

```
grant_type=ss:zxz.com:oox:grant_type:some&token=ghjsdassa
```

instead of:

```
ss%3Azxz.com%3Aoox%3Agrant_type%3Asome&token=ghjsdassa
```

so basically its not converting the **:** to %3A. if i use encodeURIComponent its becoming %253A i.e. encoding twice.

can someone suggest what to be done??

Answer (score 3):

This is because **reqUrlEncodedBody.toString()** is already applying **encodeURIComponent** to your parameters , but is reverting back some characters like ":".

See the doc from https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html

> This class accepts an optional second parameter of $QueryEncoder, which is used to serialize parameters before making a request. By default, QueryEncoder encodes keys and values of parameters using encodeURIComponent, and then un-encodes certain characters that are allowed to be part of the query according to IETF RFC 3986: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.

The code part :

```
function standardEncoding(v) {
    return encodeURIComponent(v)
        .replace(/%40/gi, '@')
        .replace(/%3A/gi, ':')
        .replace(/%24/gi, '$')
        .replace(/%2C/gi, ',')
        .replace(/%3B/gi, ';')
        .replace(/%2B/gi, '+')
        .replace(/%3D/gi, '=')
        .replace(/%3F/gi, '?')
        .replace(/%2F/gi, '/');
}
```

So if you really want yo encode thoses characters you should use a new QueryEncoder like specified in the documentation.